# Bug of selenium while trying to upload multiple pictures

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, debugging

I am working on a custom project where I want to upload some pictures with Python Selenium.

Here is my upload code:

```
    folder_path = i['full_folder_path']
    for file_name in i['images']:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".upload-images")
        element.send_keys(file_path)
```

strange thing is that pictures are uploading but in a weird way. length of i['images'] is 6 but 12 pictures are uploaded. Also they are weird duplicates of each other, I will upload pictures below of everything:

[Weird duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk0od.png)

Here is what my directory looks like:

[My directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5hSf.png)

This is printed when I print file_path:

```
C:/Projects/python/rea_back/ქირავდება დღიურად ახალი აშენებული ბინა საბურთალოზე_aoiaegimet\11356160_1.jpg
C:/Projects/python/rea_back/ქირავდება დღიურად ახალი აშენებული ბინა საბურთალოზე_aoiaegimet\11356160_2.jpg
C:/Projects/python/rea_back/ქირავდება დღიურად ახალი აშენებული ბინა საბურთალოზე_aoiaegimet\11356160_3.jpg
C:/Projects/python/rea_back/ქირავდება დღიურად ახალი აშენებული ბინა საბურთალოზე_aoiaegimet\11356160_4.jpg
C:/Projects/python/rea_back/ქირავდება დღიურად ახალი აშენებული ბინა საბურთალოზე_aoiaegimet\11356160_5.jpg
C:/Projects/python/rea_back/ქირავდება დღიურად ახალი აშენებული ბინა საბურთალოზე_aoiaegimet\11356160_6.jpg
```

names are correct in the directory as you see. Please help me to solve what is happening!

EDIT 1.0

I tried to debug my code so I added this stuff:

```
folder_path = i['full_folder_path']
uploaded_files = set() 
for file_name in i['images']:
    if file_name in uploaded_files:
        # skip the file if it has already been uploaded
        continue
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
    print(file_path)
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".upload-images")
    element.send_keys(file_path)
    uploaded_files.add(file_name)
```

This still duplicates images, I was interested if .add worked so I changed my code like this:

```
    folder_path = i['full_folder_path']
    uploaded_files = set() 
    for file_name in i['images']:
        uploaded_files.add(file_name)
        if file_name in uploaded_files:
            # skip the file if it has already been uploaded
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        print(file_path)
        element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".upload-images")
        element.send_keys(file_path)
```

and Never uploaded anything!

Comment: Perhaps the extra images are actually coming from some other part of the program that you haven't shown us?

Comment: My program doesn't engage with this input in any way, can it be uploaded still? i have code where pictures are saved but actually clicking this input is only here which code I write here

Comment: What are the twelve actual filenames that were uploaded?

Comment: Could it simply be that you ran this code twice, thus it uploaded each of the six pictures twice?

Comment: How it can be possible that I ran this code twice?

Comment: I don't know your development/testing work flow, so I can't answer that question...

Comment: I am uploading it just one time

Comment: So you have only run this code one time, ever?

Comment: Please check my edit. No I run this code multiple times but this piece code is used just one time, I mean I never click input anywhere except you see here

Comment: That second example obviously won't work -- if you call `.add()` first, then **of course** `if file_name in uploaded_files` is going to be true.

Comment: Yes, I know it won't work but duplicated files are still uploaded when it is after the code. So why? If it is true when written first, why it is false when it is written and the end?

Comment: As I mentioned before, one explanation could be that this section of code is (somehow) executed twice.  You haven't shown us the surrounding code, so we don't know if that is possible or not.

Comment: Also, what is your testing procedure?  Do you have some way of removing all the uploaded files from the sever before executing the code, to ensure you are starting from scratch?

Comment: I am removing directory manually, I am deleting folder manually.

Comment: So you can see the filenames on the server?  Are they named similarly to the original  files from your pc?  Can you post the names?

Comment: What server? I am testing my program on my pc, I have pictures with certain name in my computer and I try to upload it with selenium

Comment: "upload" generally means that you send a file from your pc to a website server.  You're not doing that?  Is the website server also hosted on your local pc?

Comment: Please check my answer John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

As it seems when we are sending keys to the input element in the loop, on each iteration previous input is not cleared. So for example if in the first loop send keys were sending image1.jpg, in the next loop, it would send image1, image1.jpg, image2.jpg, and in next loop it would send image1, image1.jpg, image1.jpg image2.jpg image2.jpg, image3.jpg etc...

Fix was this:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".upload-images")
folder_path = i['full_folder_path']
file_extension = ".jpg"

# get a list of all file names in the folder with the specified extension
file_names = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(file_extension)]

# generate the string for each file path
file_paths = []
for k, file_name in enumerate(file_names):
  file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
  file_index = k + 1
  file_paths.append(f"{file_path[:-4]}{file_extension}")

 result = "\n".join(file_paths)
 element.send_keys(result)
```